# Gráfico por semanas

Tags: highcharts, google-charts

Olá, a todos estou tentando montar um gráfico que exiba os dados agrupados por semanas, como no exemplo abaixo:
[image: Exemplo do que preciso]

Neste exemplo no Domimog teve 2 registros, Segunda 2 registros, Terça 1 registro...

Estou tentando com plugins, bibliotecas (Chats.js, google chart, etc) mas ainda não consegui fazer neste formato.

Aceito sugestões de alternativas.

Observação, utilizo angular js no meu projeto.

Comment: Segue exemplo com Chart.js  : https://jsfiddle.net/tk0hq5f4/   e outro com Google Charts: https://jsfiddle.net/pxh17xh4/     em nenhum destes eu consegui mostrar mais de um registro por dia.

Answer (score 0):

Eu usaria o gráfico de linhas no chartjs.org ficaria uma estrutura parecida com:

```
var myBarChart = new Chart(cox).Line(data, options);
var data = {
labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
datasets: [
    {
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    },
    {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    }
]
};
```

Esse exemplo é para meses, você pode trocar facilmente para semanas. Agrupe os dados no servidor e no caso teria apenas um dataset, cada dataset é uma linha no gráfico.

Ou pode-se utilizar o gráfico de barras, o dataset é o mesmo o que muda é só o tipo do gráfico:

```
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, options);
```

Agrupe os dados no servidor e pegue-os via Ajax

Comment: Obrigado Giovanni pelo exemplo, estou tentando aqui, com dificuldades em "agrupar os dados"

Comment: Se estiver usando base de dados pesquise como extrair o dia da semana na dada e faça um **count(colunadados) as numero group by DayOfWeek(data) as semana order by semana**

Comment: Cara, legal! consegui recuperar os dados agrupados. mas como ficaria no dataset? você teria u exemplo com dados fixos mesmo? de como ficaria estes  dados no dataset?   Obrigado amigo!

Comment: No exemplo da resposta dentro de datasets tem um parâmetro data que é um array, ele é o campo dos dados agrupados, cada posição do array deve bater com o campo labels que está fora do dataset. O campo data é o valor das colunas, e o campo labels suas respectivas legendas.

Comment: Amigo obrigado mesmo pela força, mas não estou conseguindo sacar como colocar mais de um registro, por exemplo, como colocar 3 itens para o domingo?  segue como estou tentando fazer: https://jsfiddle.net/tk0hq5f4/

Comment: Não tinha percebido dois pontos no mesmo dia, nesse caso cada conjunto é um dataset. Nunca vi nas bibliotecas de gráfico algo que faça mais de um ponto no mesmo data set, mas você pode emular isso com mais de um. https://jsfiddle.net/tk0hq5f4/2/ se quiser que fique igual, coloque strokeColor como transparent e vai aparecer apenas os pontos.

Comment: Caramba amigo, legal a propriedade "transparent" vai emular o que preciso. Vou tentar agora fazer desta forma, obrigado!